# Does "gemacht" also mean "something done too artificially"?

Tags: idiom

I remember someone using the word "gemacht" do describe something that was done too artificially. (In this case it was a dance move that was supposed to be spontaneous but looked too pre-planned.)

I looked for mentions of this usage on the internet but couldn't find any. Is this usage of the word known?

Comment: I'm not sure what that someone said in full, but I'd have used the attribute "künstlich". - In other contexts note that "ein gemachter Mann" is something like a wealthy man

Comment: Synonyme können sein: Gestellt, gespielt (Herzlichkeit auf einem Photo) und gefälscht.

Comment: Frau macht sich auch schick.. und wenn sie fertig ist, hat sie sich schick gemacht

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it is but it is not universally applicable. It is used a lot in context of female breasts (see [here](https://www.google.de/search?q=I%27ve%20been%20learning%20for%202%20years%20only&rlz=1C1DVCJ_enDE430DE443&oq=I%27ve%20been%20learning%20for%202%20years%20only&aqs=chrome..69i57.12123j0j4&sourceid=chrome&espv=2&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8#q=br%C3%BCste%20%22die%20sind%20doch%20gemacht%22)). There might be other examples from other fields too but I would recommend not using it actively unless you've heard it used in th respective context before.

Comment: Sagt man *gemacht* für Lippen nicht?

Comment: @c.p. Nein, die sind *gespritzt* ;)

Comment: You can surely say Lippen gemacht, I would even say you hear that more often in colloquial speaking.

Answer (score 4):

In your context I'd rather use `gewollt` (*deliberate*) or `gekünstelt` (*artificial and slightly awkward*).

In general, `gemacht` means but `made`/`created`/`accomplished`. There is however an idiomatic meaning of `being well-off` as in `ein gemachter Mann` (cf. comment by @Hagen von Eitzen)

Answer (score 0):

From context you have to think of  "Diese Brüste sind (künstlich/vom Schönheitschirurgen/ mit Silikon) gemacht".